# Using 'got' to mean 'have'

Tags: have-got

I'm used to hearing expressions like 'I got no money' or 'I got a lot of work to do', in which 'got' is used with the same meaning as 'have'. My British friends, however, always put strange faces when I say them. Is it correct to use 'got' instead of 'have' in these sentences? (I guess it's not proper English, but anyway, do people use it in casual speech?)

Comment: A more correct way, which is also common in the U.K., is to say *"I've got no money"*. Americans tend to leave out the *'ve* when they're speaking informally. We're less likely to leave out the *'s* in *"he's got no money"*, although some people do that, too.

Comment: So far *I've got no money* or *got no money* are the versions I hear in the US. However, *I got xxx* is what I've heard outside the US.

Answer (score -1):

You should also remember that in this case "got " is the past participle. If you want to use it in the present, you should say I get, which is a tad strange,

Comment: In 'I have got no money', *got* is not being used as a verb. It is the equivalent of saying 'I am *in possession of* no money', which I adjudge to be an adverbial phrase. So in 'I've *got* no money', *got* which is indeed a past participle seems to be employed as an adverb. Therefore the question of converting it to a present tense does not arise.

Comment: @WS2 The past/passive participle of *get* is *got* only in your hemisphere; in mine it is *gotten*.

Comment: @StoneyB - It's not quite that simple. See http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html

Comment: @StoneyB  Would there be a difference in meaning in your hemisphere between 'I've got a cold', and 'I've gotten a cold'? It is true that if needing to express the latter most British people will say something like 'I've gone and got a cold'.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, indeed. "I've got a cold" = "I have a cold - so I won't be at the meeting." "I've gotten a cold" would be used with "Since last Thursday..." or "Every time I've been to Denver...".

Comment: It is still the case that "got" alone is somehow used as a present tense, which should be "get". Whether it is the past participle or the simple past, it is still incorrect.